# Proof that function is increasing

Tags: monotone-functions

How to prove that the function $$y(x)=x(\ln(x+1) - \ln(x))$$ is increasing on $[0,1]$?
The derivative test requires to analyze equally challenging function $\ln{\left(\frac{x+1}{x}\right)}-\frac{1}{x+1}.$ Are there more ways to prove that $y(x)$ is strictly increasing?

Comment: Use $\log(\frac{x+1}{x})=-\log(1-\frac{1}{x+1})=\sum_{k\geq 1}\frac{1}{k(x+1)^k}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write your derivative as $$\ln{\left(1+\frac1x\right)}-\frac{\frac1x}{1+\frac1x}$$ and use the inequality $$\ln{(1+x)}>\frac{x}{1+x}$$ for $0<x<1$.

---

**Edit:** By definition $$\ln{(1+x)}:=\int_{1}^{1+x}\frac1tdt>\frac1{1+x}\int_{1}^{1+x}dt=\frac{x}{1+x}$$ where the inequality in the middle comes from the fact that $1/t$ is strictly decreasing.

Comment: Could you, please, elaborate where this inequality comes from?

Comment: ... which is just a reformulation of $e^x\ge 1+x$